# gnuplot pdfcairo matches latex font size

Tags: latex, gnuplot, cairo

I plot a pdf figure using gnuplot 5.0 with pdfcairo terminal, and then insert this figure into a pdf file using latex. However, I found the font size in gunplot is different with the font size in latex, although I set them to be the same.

To make the font size consistent in gnuplot and latex, I have to set the fontscale in gnuplot as 0.75, as shown in the following codes.

gnuplot codes: plot an 'A' in blue (Helvetica, size 12, fontscale 0.75).

```
set terminal pdfcairo font 'Helvetica,12' size 1cm,1cm fontscale 0.75
set output 'test0.pdf'
set xrange [-1:1]
set yrange [-1:1]
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset border
set label 'A' at 0,0 textcolor 'blue'
p 1/0 notitle
```

Latex codes: insert the previous figure in original size, and write a black 'A' (Helvetica, size 12) next to the previous 'A'.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics{test0.pdf}};
\node at (0.3, -0.025) {\textsf{A}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[You can see the final pdf file here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otbgR.png) Now we can see these two 'A' are exactly the same size under the gnuplot setting 'fontscale 0.75'. I don't understand why 'fontscale 0.75' should be used in gnuplot, not 'fontscale 1'?
Is this a problem of cairo? And is there any elegant way to deal with this font size issue?

---

Short answer: gnuplot uses 72dpi, while cairo uses 96dpi. (96/72=4/3)

Note: For the same reason, if using pngcairo, 'fontscale 0.75' should also be used to get the right font size.

Alternative solution: cairolatex. @user8153

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but if you can want to match latex font sizes (and all other aspects of text rendering) in your figures you can use the `cairolatex` terminal, which leaves the text rendering to latex.

Comment: @user8153 Thank you for your suggestion. Because I also use the figures in other places, I need show the text in the figure.

Comment: If you want you can do that with `cairolatex` as well -- you generate a `standalone` latex file and then run pdflatex over it, which you can do from within the gnuplot script. For example: `set term cairolatex pdf standalone header "\\usepackage{amsmath}" font ",9" size 3.4167in,2in; set outp "test.tex"; plot sin(x); set outp; system "pdflatex test.tex"` The advantage is that you get the full range of Latex abilities and consistency with other, Latex-generated text.

Comment: @user8153 Nice, I don't know this before. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this might be due to cairo rendering. In order to set the font size, Gnuplot calls function [pango_font_description_set_size](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Fonts.html#pango-font-description-set-size) with the supplied size, i.e., 12 in your case. However, this is then translated into the cairo units:

> the size of the font in points, scaled by PANGO_SCALE. (That is, a
>   size value of 10 * PANGO_SCALE is a 10 point font. The conversion
>   factor between points and device units depends on system configuration
>   and the output device. For screen display, a logical DPI of 96 is
>   common, in which case a 10 point font corresponds to a 10 * (96 / 72)
>   = 13.3 pixel font.

Moreveor, from the documentation of the function `pango_cairo_font_map_set_resolution`:

```
/**
 * pango_cairo_font_map_set_resolution:
 * @fontmap: a #PangoCairoFontMap
 * @dpi: the resolution in "dots per inch". (Physical inches aren't actually
 *   involved; the terminology is conventional.)
 *
 * Sets the resolution for the fontmap. This is a scale factor between
 * points specified in a #PangoFontDescription and Cairo units. The
 * default value is 96, meaning that a 10 point font will be 13
 * units high. (10 * 96. / 72. = 13.3).
 *
 * Since: 1.10
 **/
```

So in summary, it seems that the supplied size is then for the purposes of the rendering multiplied by `96/72 = 4/3` which effectively yields a font of size 16 instead of 12. The scaling factor of `0.75` which you applied would then revert this.

Comment: Thank you. Finally I understand. [Cairo uses 96dpi](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pango-0.13.5.0/docs/Graphics-Rendering-Pango-Cairo.html), and it converts font sizes (in points, pt) to Cairo units (in pixels), e.g., 10pt * (1/72 inch/pt) * (96 pixel/inch) = 13.3 pixel as shown in your answer. However, [gnuplot uses 72dpi](http://gensoft.pasteur.fr/docs/gnuplot/5.0.4/node483.html). So this inconsistency results in the larger font size with factor 4/3.